# How do I get data storage used on my AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using AWS RDS. To start with I started with storage of 10 GB. I need to import more data into my MySQL. Need to know how much free space is available ! How can I do that ? It is not an EC2 instance on which I could have run df linux command.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have a look at the `FreeStorageSpace` metric.

It can be found in **Cloudwatch**, under **RDS** metrics.

[image: Metric in Cloudwatch]

Comment: I use AWS console only; and not any AWS API. On AWS console; I do not see FreeStorageSpace shown !! Metrics shown are "Freeable Memory", "Freeable Space" and I do not think these two metrics answers my question.

Comment: @Smamatti This answers the question, it's not a request.

Comment: @Deepak I can see the metric in the console.

Comment: that screenshot is pretty much useless

Comment: FYI, if anyone else was confused as I was seeing a reported 524G of free storage space reported in the "FreeStorageSpace" graph on an instance with 512GB provisioned, it's because the y-axis of the graph is reporting "524G" to mean 524 billion bytes, as opposed to 524GB. So 524,000,000000 / 1024^3 = 488GB, versus "524G" shown as the label on the y-axis of the graph. If you hover over the line in the graph, it explicitly shows you the 524,000,000,000 (or whatever) bytes value.

Answer (score 15):

From the RDS Instances console, you can select an instance and click "Show Monitoring". The "Freeable Space" chart is the same information. Click the chart for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics  --start-time $(TZ=PST+1 date +%FT%T) --end-time $(TZ=PST date +%FT%T) --period 3600 --namespace AWS/RDS --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=${yourRDSname} --metric-name FreeStorageSpace
```

How I got --dimensions Name:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --output json | less
```

How I got metric-name:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html
```

Comment: So as --unit Megabytes didnt work, I am using:
| awk 'NF==4{Z=$2/(1024^3);print Z}'

Answer (score 2):

Go to RDS instance

- Click on Configuration, note down the storage(total)
- Click on Monitoring, check matrics "Free storage space" and note down free storage space.
- Do simple subtraction : Total - Free storage = Your answer (storage in Use)

Don't forget to convert GB to MB :D

Answer (score -2):

1. Open the CloudWatch console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/.
2. If necessary, change the AWS Region. From the navigation bar, choose the AWS Region where your AWS resources are. For more information, see Regions and Endpoints.
3. In the navigation pane, choose Metrics. Choose the RDS metric namespace.
4. Choose a metric dimension, Database Class.
5. Select freeable memory from list

[image: Image for free memory]

Comment: The user asked about free space to import data, so I don't think FreeableMemory address the question.  It is otherwise nearly a duplicate of the aa.

Comment: If u see in his question he mentioned he wants to know this - Need to know how much free space is available   @rubyisbeautiful... Pls read the question again

Comment: The OP is clearly asking about "storage" space, which would be reflected in the FreeStorageSpace metric.  FreeableMemory refers to RAM, which might be helpful for importing data, but isn't their question.  To wit, they point out that they can't run the "df" command, which would indicate available drive space.